# ERROR Cannot read property 'transpile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

Trying to run my team mates vuejs nuxt frontend app so I can code the backend API endpoints for it but its giving me an issue. Could someone assist me?

```
ash@heaven-laptop:~/Desktop/dp-work/git-repos/core-pwa$ npm run dev

> frontend@1.0.0 dev /home/ash/Desktop/dp-work/git-repos/core-pwa
> nuxt

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                                         13:47:25
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                                            13:47:25
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                       13:47:25
ℹ Waiting for server resources...                                                                                                           13:47:25
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                                      13:47:25

 ERROR  Cannot read property 'transpile' of undefined                                                                                       13:47:25

  at WebpackClientConfig.normalizeTranspile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4367:58)
  at new WebpackBaseConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4332:36)
  at new WebpackClientConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4800:5)
  at WebpackBundler.getWebpackConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5254:20)
  at WebpackBundler.build (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5262:12)
  at Builder.build (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:5518:30)
  at <anonymous>

ℹ Waiting for server resources...                                                                                                           13:47:26
ℹ Waiting for server resources... (repeated 3 times)                                                                                        13:47:26
ℹ Waiting for server resources...                                                                                                           13:48:01
```

Comment: show your nuxt.config and package.json